# Add data by increasing mongodb id

Tags: python, mongodb

If the data has been added before and the id number is 1, I want the id number of the new data to be added to be 2. I want it to increase in order.

I want it to read the id number of the previous data in the mongodb database and increase it accordingly.

How can I do it?

I'm coding with python.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: @12944qwerty I resorted to the name method. But if I do that, the same names can get mixed up. That's why I resorted to the id method.

Comment: Ok, but what have you attempted with the ID method so far then?

Comment: @12944qwert nothing. I just tried the name method.